# Mobile data is turn on itself

Tags: data-connection

I am using android, it started a week ago. It automatically turns on mobile data. I switched it off but after a couple of minutes it again gets switched on. Please suggest me to solve this problem.
its koreaios8

Answer (score 0):

One of your apps is controlling your data connection. Find it and remove it. You can try clearing app cash. And last you can try factory reset.